# Show DIV Text based on Multiple Selections jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have tried to search google and here about my question but havent found the exact answer which I could use. So I am asking here. Hope to find help.

I have some input fields in a form and want to show a DIV using jQuery. The details (pseudo-logic) are as follows.

```
V1: <input type="radio" name="rad" value="v1" />
V2: <input type="radio" name="rad" value="v2" />
<select name="sel">
<option value="o1">o1</option>
<option value="o2">o2</option>
</select>
```

Now, based on selection, the jQuery will generate the text in an initially empty hidden div based on data filled in form fields.

For example, as it may be shown

```
<div id="d1">
The calculated value for rad(o1) & o2 & t1 is "value1"
</div>
```

If it was only for PHP, the simple code I could use, to be processed in another php file, would be (using mysql query, and I am aware of real escape strings, just not mentioning here),

```
$radioBtn = $_POST['rad'];
$selDrpDn = $_POST['sel'];
$textData = $_POST['t1'];

//Using this query, 
$queryString = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobiles WHERE jobType = '$radioBTN' AND modelName = '$selDrpDn' AND compName = '$textData'");
```

Comment: You want to hide/show the div elements based on what option was selected?

Comment: 1. You have not provided enough information for anyone to help you. 2. You have not provided any code showing what you've tried .. what did not work and what we can help with.

Comment: @jsickles Oh, sorry, its going to be only one hiddev div which will be shown with generated text based on when all fields are filled.

Comment: @user3558931 brother if I post the original code, it will be long and ambigous as without the database structure i am using.

If above code can be made possible, which is "Show an initially empty hidden div with text generated by jQuery based on data from form fields when all filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your question...

```
$(function() {
    $("select[name='sel'], input[name='rad']").on("change",function() {
         $('#d1').html("You selected : " + this.value).show();
    }
});
```

that's using the form code and div sample you gave above.